# For each testcase, input an integer n (0 <= n <= 10)

Tags: c, functional-programming

I am solving problem in a online judge and I faced a problem. I think my code is correct but unfortunately the judge says wrong answer. Where did I made mistake?

Habib has learned so much about programming in the last few days! Today he faces a new challenge, handling input with test cases! For this, he must solve a set of inputs and for each input h must generate an output. And what is better than to practice this other than calculating factorials?! A factorial of an integer `N` is calculated by multiplying all the integers from `1 to N`. For example, `4!` (4 factorial) is calculated as- `1x2x3x4=24`. In this problem, Habib is required to solve a set of inputs for a defined number of test cases. For example, if `testcase = 3`, then he must take `3` set of inputs and generate `3` sets of desired outputs, one output for one input. Help him solve the problem.

**Input**

The input starts with an integer Test (0 < Test < 100) which denoted number of inputs or testcases to be solved. For each testcase, input an integer n (0 <= n <= 10).

**Output**

For each testcase generate output in a single line in the format: `Case x: y`, where x is the testcase number and y is the answer for calculating n!.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,Test,n=0,x,j,y,s=1;
    scanf("%d",&Test);
    for(i=1;i<=Test;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            s=s*j;
        }
        printf("Case %d: %d\n",i,s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I think my code is correct" Why on earth do you think this code is correct? Didn't you do any tests?

Comment: Off-topic: Your task is not to write code for him but to help him solve the problem. Bad problem for online judge system...

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to reset `s` for each test cases.

Try adding `s=1;` after `scanf("%d",&n);`.

Answer (score 0):

> Input The input starts with an integer Test (0 < Test < 100) which denoted number of inputs or testcases to be solved. For each testcase, input an integer n (0 <= n <= 10).

Your code does not reflect this. You should definitely check if the inputs are valid or not, a way could be:

```
if(Test < 100 && Test > 0){
  //do something
}else{
    printf("Invalid input!");
    }
```

Furthermore you should consider staying with either capital variable names or only lowercase, example: `int test,n` or `int Test, N`. Mixing both makes bigger projects a guessing game when you have to edit it after a few days.

Now to your Task:
Basically your task is to find n! and do this X-times.

As stated by @MikeCat you never reset your s, which is the starting point for your factorial.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i,test,n=0,x,j,y,s=1;
scanf("%d",&Test);
if(!(test <100 && test > 0)){
    printf("Invalid input!");
}
for(i=1;i<=test;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    s = 1;
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        s=s*j;
    }
    printf("Case %d: %d\n",i,s);
}
return 0;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
 {
    int i,Test,n=0,x,j,y;
    scanf("%d",&Test);
    for(i=1;i<=Test;i++)
    {
        int s=1;//observe this 
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
             s=s*j;
        }
        printf("Case %d: %d\n",i,s);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: After you `//observe this`, what if the user enters `2147483647` for `n` (or `Test` for that matter)? Where is your *input validation*? (e.g. checking the return of `scanf` and validating `Test` and `n` are within the proper ranges?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, but the question clearly mentions that `0<=n<=10` in input cases range. This means the input file contains n between 0 and 10 **only**.And the online judge ensures that. You do not need to explicitly ensure that in the code.

Comment: That's why there was no downvote, but traditionally, if providing full-example code (as you have done), you will want to provide a minimum complete validated example so you are providing proper guidance for the new programmers you are helping.